# Run batch file from python and get return values

Tags: python, batch-file, return, subprocess, return-value

I have a python script which runs a batch script. The batch script sets 3 new variables, which I want to return, so that I can use them in the python script. I decided to use `subprocess.popen` since I read that rather than `call` or `run`, this allows for the `communicate()` function to retrieve return values.

My python script is as follows atm:

```
import subprocess
import os 

batch = "C:/desktop/mybatch.bat"
p = subprocess.run([batch, &echo(!var1!&echo(!var2!&echo(!var3!)))], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
var_1, var_2, var_3 = stdout.splitlines()
print(var_1)
print(var_2)
print(var_3)

os.system("pause")
```

My batch file is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set "var1_type=" & for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('
    2^>nul reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\UserSession /v WarnOnClose
    ') do if not defined var1_type set "var1_type=%%A"
set "var1_value=" & for /f "tokens=3" %%B in ('
    2^>nul reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\UserSession /v WarnOnClose
    ') do if not defined var1_value set "var1_value=%%B"
    
set "var2_type=" & for /f "tokens=2" %%C in ('
    2^>nul reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\UserSession /v SerialLine
    ') do if not defined var2_type set "var2_type=%%C"
set "var2_value=" & for /f "tokens=3" %%D in ('
    2^>nul reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\UserSession /v SerialLine
    ') do if not defined var2_value set "var2_value=%%D"

set "var3_type=" & for /f "tokens=2" %%E in ('
    2^>nul reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\UserSession /v SerialSpeed
    ') do if not defined var3_type set "var3_type=%%E"
set "var3_value=" & for /f "tokens=3" %%F in ('
    2^>nul reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\UserSession /v SerialSpeed
    ') do if not defined var3_value set "var3_value=%%F"

set var1=!var1_type!!var1_value!
set var2=!var2_type!!var2_value!
set var3=!var3_type!!var3_value!

exit /b 0
```

When I run the python script, nothing happens. I do not see an error. The python window opens for a split second, then closes automatically. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Thanks! I spent days trying to figure out reading registry values directly from Python but could not manage it. That's why I chose to do it over a batch file, which I could write in a much shorter time.